# How to make a node draggable when context menu is open in gojs?

Tags: angular7, gojs

I'm opening the context menu when the picture in the node gets hovered. As a result, I'm unable to drag the node without closing it. Would be better if there is an option to close the context menu when drag is attempted.

GoJS version - GoJS 2.0

[Sample gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs3m1.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the **ContextMenuTool** and are using GoJS context menus (i.e. **Adornment**s instead of **HTMLInfo**s), then you could do something like:

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  { . . .,
    "contextMenuTool.doMouseDown": function() {
      if (this.isActive &&
          this.currentContextMenu instanceof go.Adornment &&
          !this.currentContextMenu.actualBounds.containsPoint(this.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint)) {
        this.stopTool();
        this.diagram.toolManager.doMouseDown();
        return;
      }
      go.ContextMenuTool.prototype.doMouseDown.call(this);
    }
  })
```